# how to run complex sql of cassandra via node js

Tags: node.js, express, cassandra, cql

I am trying to run complex sql of cassandra from node.js and using cassandra express package for it and below is query:

```
client.execute("select distinct c.objekt PSP, b.bestellung purchase_order, b.details, b.bestellnettowert Budget, c.Interim_Amounts, c.belegdatum, b.cost_centre
                                from
                                            (select objekt, sum("Wert/KWahr") Interim_Amounts, belegdatum, bestellung from bdr.cj74 where year(belegdatum) = '2016' group by objekt, belegdatum, bestellung) c,
                                            (select bestellung, "Lieferant/Lieferwerk" details, bestellnettowert, belegdatum, "PSP-Elm", "Kostenst." cost_centre  from bdr.opexcapex where year(opexcapex.belegdatum) = '2016') b
                                where b."PSP-Elm" = c.objekt
                                            and year(c.belegdatum) = year(b.belegdatum)
                                            and c.bestellung = b.bestellung", [],

function(err, result) {
```

If I run simple select statement it is working and any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you can't.  Cassandra supports CQL, not SQL.  CQL has similar syntax to SQL, but many of the SQL keywords behave differently in CQL.

For instance, you cannot do things like JOINs or subqueries.  It does allow you to do things like DISTINCT and some aggregations like SUM, but there are restrictions on when and how you can use those methods (only allowed on certain keys).  Here's a link to the docs on querying with aggregations: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/latest/cql/cql_using/useQueryStdAggregate.html .

Also, aggregations are new as of Cassandra 3.0.  If you're running on a 2.x version, your only option is to do some of that processing on the client-side.